# Adding perl script to module distribution and making it accessible globally

Tags: perl

I'm wondering if there is a tutorial or simple way to add perl scripts which I've written to be accessible to the user globally.

for eg. you apps like Carton, Cpanm, much like how npm has an `npm install -g` option.

I tried placing my scripts in the bin directory of my perl package but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

The `App::*` area of cpan contains installable tools and utilities. Looking at a small one, like [`App::p`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/IRONCAMEL/App-p-0.0304/lib/App/p.pm) I saw that [its structure](https://api.metacpan.org/source/IRONCAMEL/App-p-0.0304/) looked like it contained a [`Makefile.PL`](https://api.metacpan.org/source/IRONCAMEL/App-p-0.0304/Makefile.PL) that used [`ExtUtils::MakeMaker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker::Tutorial) to define how to build test and [install](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.04/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm#make_install) the relatively [small perl script](https://api.metacpan.org/source/IRONCAMEL/App-p-0.0304/bin/p).

However, if you're talking about just taking a script you wrote and making it something executable by you, the user, then it's basically the same way all scripting works (apologies if you weren't asking this):

One Unix, Linux and Mac OS X when using a shell like `bash`:

1. Any file can be made executable to the user by running `chmod u+x filename`
2. An executable file should start with a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number), for plain text files containing scripts, the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is that number. So start your files with (as covered in [`man perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Safety-net)):

   > ```
   > #!/usr/bin/perl
   > use strict;
   > use warnings;
   > ```
3. When specifying an executable file from the command line you can type in the full path, possibly with conveniences from your shell. EG the file is at `$HOME/myscripts/runme.pl` you can type that at the prompt, the expanded `/home/username/myscripts/runme.pl` (`/Users/username/myscripts/runme.pl` on Mac OS X) or `~/myscripts/runme.pl` at a `bash` prompt. Or if `runme.pl` is in your current working directory: `./runme.pl`
4. If you just type `runme.pl` `sh` and `bash` and many shells will search your `PATH` variable in order and run the first `runme.pl` in any of the specified paths.

   - So if `echo $PATH` gives you something like: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` and you want the example in point 3 to work with just `runme.pl` you should
   - Either move the file into one of those directories (not recommended).
   - Or add `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/myscripts` to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` file or likewise for your preferred shell. Be sure to open a new login shell session, EG close that terminal window and open a new one.

On Windows, this is an exercise left to the reader. ☺